# WL 6.0 Sever Update date time in app?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Using Direct Update, organizations are able to update the web content of their deployed HTML5 and hybrid applications directly from the IBM Mobile Application Platform Server upon application startup.

If we login on worlight console it displays for each app:

"Last updated at: 2014-07-18 16:40"

Is there a way to show this value in app ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in functionality to get the timestamp of an update, so maybe what you could do is:

- have some JS variable
- whenever you are about to deploy an update - update the variable's value (a timestamp)
- display it somewhere in your app

This way whenever there is an update, the new value will be displayed. So it will be an approximate timestamp.

Comment: Thanks @Idan Adar, already doing that, wanted to reduce a step, is there a function that we can invoke on direct update ?

Comment: In Worklight 6.0 there are no 'hooks' available for Direct Update; Worklight 6.2, though, does provide this. In this case, you can likely check whether or not the timestamp value has changed after a successful connect to the Worklight Server. Id yes, this means a direct update took place, and so you can invoke some action.

Comment: Timestamp value for ? And is this timestamp only in 6.2 ?

Comment: I am referring to the variable mentioned in my answer that contains a value that you will need to update with every deployment. In 6.2 you can create custom Direct Update behavior, please refer to the user documentation about that.